# Is it possible to have shiny server pro login only for selected routes

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have shiny application, and to use the app user need to be authenticated using LDAP but user should be able to use the API without login.

My api is created using:

```
    shiny:::handlerManager$addHandler(
      shiny:::routeHandler(url, handler),
      key
    )
```

where url always start with `/api` is it possible to configure shiny server pro to allow to open /api urls without login? (I don't have code of the login part yet because I'm investigating if it's possible to have only part of the application behind login).